# Reliability of User Properties (Persistance?)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a number of Calendar Event IDs (0 < n <= 9) for each project (of which there are ~50). To get a *single* piece of information, the event(s) (`location`), I use `calendar.getEventSeriesById(_event_id_).getLocation()`.

This is supposed to be a flexible UI that my boss can use to view the details of <= 9 different events, for any particular project. However, when populating the UI with this information, this single call *significantly* slow down execution time (up to 10 seconds to load 5 events, depending on server load).

Since `UserProperties` are account-bound, and **all** my scripts run under the same "boss" (manager) account, would `UserProperties` be a ***reliable*** solution to storing 200+ `eventIDs` *per semester* (4 month period)? Since none of my other scripts set properties, and calendar event IDs are unique, I don't need to worry about collision/overwrites. However, this system relies *heavily* on these key/value pairs, so is there any concern with `UserProperties` being cleared through some automated process (not by my scripts nor me manually), or some other form of corruption?

Are there more ways to avoid excessive calls to `CalendarApp` for this use case? Or are `Spreadsheets`/`UserProperties` the only real options? -> aside from a database, which is also excessive...

**Edit**: I did implement this as a test, and the load times for the UI improved on average about 500%, which is great. But are there any reliability concerns related with `UserProperties`, or `ScriptProperties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is *strictly* about reliability, the answer is definitely **yes you can** count on it ( apart from a bug a couple of years ago I never experience any failure) but, as Zig mentioned in his answer, [ScriptDb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/?hl=fr-FR) is *made for that* and is better protected since no one can access it through the "normal" Ui and accidentally corrupt data.
Moreover it is intended to work with objects which simplifies the process if you need to store anything else than string values.

Comment: Eventually I will convert this system to use ScriptDB, but at the current moment I'm looking for a quick workaround *without* having to use the DB. This answers my question, I'll probably have more about ScriptDB in the future XD

Answer (score 1):

Use neither, they are not for that. Use scriptDb. The gas help page on storing data explains this further. See gas help and this https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBjb7o4DDA

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a look at it later when I have some free time :)